# Immunological factors for the cause of headaches following SAR-CoV-2/COVID vaccination

Tags: immunology, vaccination, covid

It is [generally-accepted](https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/vaccines/expect/after.html) that headaches are a common side effect from receiving the COVID vaccine.

> Vaccine recipients with pre-existing immunity experience systemic side effects with a significantly higher frequency than antibody naïve vaccines (e.g., fatigue, headache, chills, fever, muscle or join pains, in order of decreasing frequency, P < 0.001 for all listed symptoms, Fisher’s exact test, two-sided).

— Florian Krammer et al.: "Robust spike antibody responses and increased reactogenicity in seropositive individuals after a single dose of SARS-CoV-2 mRNA vaccine" doi: https://doi.org/10.1101/2021.01.29.21250653

**I am trying to understand why.** What theories or known biological, immunological or otherwise physiological mechanisms would cause recipients of the vaccine to report headaches as a common side effect?

Comment: Headaches are a side effect of both vaccinations and infections.  Have a look at the effects of cytokines, particularly Interferons.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Headache is one of the various side-effects of vaccination. Typically, a person will have pain in the site of injection, muscles throughout your body and head.

The immunological reason is the network of our immune system. Whenever a foreign antigen (vaccine) is detected by our immune system, antigen-presenting-cells (macrophages, dendritic cells) takes the antigen to nearest lymph nodes where it is presented to the adaptive immune system. Due to this invasion, strong immune response starts which leads to the pain.

[image]

Image Source: wikipedia.org/wiki/Lymphatic_system

Comment: Thanks for the amazing answer @Riq (I would upvote you +1 but I don't have enough rep!) -- one quick followup question for you, if you don't mind. It _sounds_ like you're saying that when cells, such as macrophages, present lymph nodes with antigens (from the vaccine) this initiates an immune system response, which you say leads to "pain". But why headaches? Why is this pain so specific to the head? Thanks for any clarification!

Comment: BTW I am _not_ the one who gave you a downvote! I am happy with your answer so far!

Comment: @IamYourFaja You can accept the answer if you think it answered your question.

Comment: Yes thanks again @Riq, do you have any ideas regarding my followup question above ("_But why headaches?..._") Perhaps something to do with the cytokines and interferons that Polypine mentioned?

Comment: @IamYourFaja yeah, cytokines are essentially the communicator of our immune system. They help in cell signaling and involved in various side effects of our immune system. Hope this clarifies your follow-up question.